Bind column name into a prepared statement
I have this
interface CustomFooRepository {
    fun findByValueIgnoreCase(query: String, type: RequestType): List<Foo>
}

class CustomFooRepositoryImpl(
    @PersistenceContext private val entityManager: EntityManager
) : CustomFooRepository {

    override fun findByValueIgnoreCase(query: String, type: RequestType): List<Foo> {
        val column = when (type) {
            RequestType.first_name -> "first_name"
            RequestType.last_name -> "last_name"
            RequestType.email -> "email"
        }

        val sql = """
            SELECT 
                *,
                SIMILARITY(:column, :query) AS score
            FROM foo
            WHERE :column iLIKE :queryWildcard
            ORDER BY score DESC NULLS LAST, :column
            LIMIT 20;
        """

        val constructedQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Foo::class.java)
        constructedQuery.setParameter("column", column)
        constructedQuery.setParameter("queryWildcard", "%" + query + "%")
        constructedQuery.setParameter("query", query)
        return constructedQuery.resultList as List<Foo>
    }
}


interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, CustomFooRepository

Which returns me zero rows (which is wrong). I assume this is because I am trying to bind a column name using a prepared statement (in the WHERE clause).
Is there any way to make this work?

Another ugly way to do this is make the score a case expression and the where clause somthing like
(:column = 'first_name' AND first_name iLIKE :queryWildcard OR ...) ,
but why don't you build your query string according to the request type, leaving you with no column parameter?

I believe you could try something like this :
val sql = """
        SELECT 
            *,
            SIMILARITY($column, :query) AS score
        FROM foo
        WHERE $column iLIKE :queryWildcard
        ORDER BY score DESC NULLS LAST, $column
        LIMIT 20;
    """


This will work. Unfortunately, it might cause some tools (such as SonarQube) to incorrectly report an SQL injection issue. Just make sure that the value of column can only possibly come from your own code.
